# External Display is connected but only shows blue

Tags: macbook-pro, display, hdmi

I have a early 2015 Retina Macbook. I recently got a Dell 1707FP monitor to use as an external display and I have an Aukey CB-C26 hub that provides me with an HDMI port. I'm using an Amazon basics HDMI to VGI cable. When I connect the monitor, the laptop recognizes an external monitor is connected but the monitor is just a blank blue screen. I know the cable works because when I connect using the same cable to my Windows laptop the monitor works fine. I also know my Aukey adapter works when I connect it to my TV using an HDMI cable.

Here's the odd thing. If I restart my Macbook while it's connected to the external display, when the login page appears it appears on the external display. As soon as I put in my password, the display flickers and goes blue while the Macbook screen wakes up. So, the display is getting a usable signal at least some of the time. Any idea what is causing the blue screen on the external display and if there's anything I can do to change it?

Answer (score 1):

There are a number of possible causes and related solutions, but let's start with the most obvious solution first.

**Reset your PRAM/NVRAM**

Older Macs had what's called Parameter RAM (PRAM), newer Macs use Non-Volatile Random-Access Memory (NVRAM). I suggest you reset this, here’s how:

1. **Shut down your machine.** Yes, a full shut down, not just logging out.
2. **Press the <kbd>power button</kbd> *and then* press the <kbd>command</kbd><kbd>option</kbd><kbd>p</kbd><kbd>r</kbd> keys.** You have to make sure you press these keys before the gray screen appears or it won’t work.
3. **Hold those keys down** until your Mac reboots again and you here the startup chime.
4. **Let go of the keys and let your Mac reboot normally.**

**Note:** When you log back in you ***may*** need to readjust some of your system preferences (e.g. mouse speed, time and date/timezone, etc).

Give this a go and report back with how you go.